# Why does Bitmap make the image so blurry?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, bitmap

I took a picture using the camera app and when I stored it using a Bitmap this is what it looks like:
[image: Picture of a KitKat that was stored using a Bitmap]

Why is the image so blurry? Is there another way to capture the image without distorting the quality?

Edit: Code for how the image is being captured and previewed

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val foodBitmap = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(data)!!.extras)!!["data"] as Bitmap
        food_image.setImageBitmap(foodBitmap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity#comment32535950_5991757

Comment: looks like you use preview image from Intent

Comment: @Style-7 I included the `Bitmap` line of code in my post to show how I'm getting the image.

Comment: this is preview image - not full

Comment: @Style-7 So how do I change it to get the full high-quality image instead of getting the preview?

Comment: @Style-7 You don't think I've tried that already? Why do you think I'm asking here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity see Original answer (2015) you have to create a file then pass it to Intent

Comment: @Style-7 What if I don't want to create the file and save it in the gallery? Can I still do that or is the only way to do that is get the preview?

Comment: create a tmp file in local file storage